# Why FindObjectsOfType method is returning only 1 object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to create a block breaker game with 2 levels. The score the player scores in the level 1 should persist to level 2. But the game hangs at level two. At the start of level 2 there should be 2 level objects but while debugging I found that `FindObjectsOfType<Level>()` method is returning 1.

```
public class Level : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextMeshPro text ;
    [Range(0,10)][SerializeField] float speed;
    public int blocksAvailable, points;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        blocksAvailable = countBlocks();
        points = 0;

    }
    private void Awake() {
        int levelObjectCount = FindObjectsOfType<Level>().Length;
        if (levelObjectCount > 1)  {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        text.text = points.ToString();
        if (blocksAvailable == points) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
        Time.timeScale = speed;
    }

    public int countBlocks() {
        int blocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Block").Length;
        return blocks;
    }

    public void addPoints() {
        points++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Find` is probably only returning 1, because if it returns any other larger number, the game object with that code is destroyed.

Comment: I need the newly created gameobject in level 2 to be destroyed.

Comment: Is it possible that one is inactive or disabled in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

[`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) can only find components that are **enabled** and **active** in the scene hierarchy. If for any reason this is not the case in the moment you call it you won't find that component.

> It will return no assets (meshes, textures, prefabs, ...) or inactive objects.

Also note

> Please note that this function is very slow. [...]. In most cases you can use the singleton pattern instead.

So in your case I would rather use a singleton pattern:

```
// This stays set and shared between all Level classes
// also between scenes for the entire session
private static Level instance;

private void Awake()
{
    // other instance already exists?
    if(instance)
    {
        Debug.Log("Another instance of Level already exists. Click here to highlight it in the hierarchy", instance);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }

    instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```